# How can I add each result to my table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

I have a php file (with simple_HTML_Dom) which scrape all the URLs of a CSV file.

He extract all the info I need, and all OK, but now I want to add all these results on my MySQL table.

I want each result adds in one row in MySQL table.

That's the code I have so far:

```
    <?php

    require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);



    function scrapUrl($url) 
    {

        $html = new simple_html_dom();

        $html->load_file($url);


        $names = $html->find('h1');
        $manufacturers = $html->find('h2');
        
        
        foreach ($names as $name) {
           echo $name->innertext;
           echo '<br>';
        }
        foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
           echo $manufacturer->innertext;
           echo '<br>';
           echo '<hr><br>';
        }
        

    }

    $rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.

    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));

    //print_r($csv); // Verás que es un array donde cada elemento es array con una de las url.

    foreach ($csv as $linea) {

        $url = $linea[0];
        scrapUrl($url);

    }


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    

foreach ($csv as $linea) {


 $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre, nombreFabricante) VALUES($name, $manufacturer)";
 print ("<p> $sql </p>");    
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Items added to the database!";
 } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

EDIT: I have updated the code. I have added also the price variable.
The error shown in the output is this one:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 69

Notice: Undefined variable: manufacturer in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 69

Error: INSERT INTO productos (nombre, nombreFabricante) VALUES(,)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'https://url.com/es/product1.html', )' at line 1
```

**How can I solve the error for the Notice: Undefined variable: name & price?**

**I want to add the $name and $manufacturer variables which are inside the function, to my MySQL table**

Comment: What ist the problem? What output do you get?

Comment: @ManoharSingh , okay but i have no idea of how do that :(

The outpout is (with all the extracted data below) -> 

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined variable: manufacturer in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv.php on line 70

Error: INSERT INTO productos (name, manufacturer) VALUES('', '')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you define $name so you'll need to check that it's valid.

```
foreach ($csv as $linea) {


 $sql = "INSERT INTO productos (name, manufacturer) VALUES('$name', '{$linea[0]}')";
 print ("<p> $sql </p>");    
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Items added to the database!";
 } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Hello Raz, i don't want INSERT the link in my database (that's what we do with '{$linea[0]}'. 

I want to add the $name and $manufacturer variables wich are inside the function.

Comment: @A.Sanchez are the values on each line ? Or, if possible, can you give a short example of what you're trying to do with 2-3 values ? ( i mean how it should look like )

Comment: i wan't to add the 3 scraped $variables for each scraped url with simple_html_dom to an existing MySQL table.(one url in each row, but what i wan't is not the url, what i want is the $name,$manufacturer and $price). The  problem is because in my code the 3 variables are inside the function(i think). Scraping all data is already done, but now i need to add all this data to MySQL rows so i can display it later in a simple DataTable.  I hope i have explained well. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , Hope you are collecting each value separately but your need is to insert each set of result in the mysql table as a new row , try the below but it's a rough one make it as per your need.

```
require 'libs/simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);



function scrapUrl($url) 
{

   $ar_name =array();
   $ar_man = array();

    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    $html->load_file($url);


    $names = $html->find('h1');
    $manufacturers = $html->find('h2');


    foreach ($names as $name) {
       $ar_name[] = $name->innertext;
    }
    foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
       $ar_man[] = $manufacturer->innertext;
    }

    for($i=o;$i<sizeof($ar_name);$i++)
     {


$sql = "INSERT INTO table(name, manufacturer)
VALUES ($ar_name[$i],$ar_man[$i])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
     }

    //echo $url;

}

$rutaCSV = 'csv/urls1.csv'; // Ruta del csv.

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($rutaCSV));
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant o - assumed 'o' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: o in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: o in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 48

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\csv2.php on line 48

Comment: Give mysql connection properly and check it , i shown the code for a reference only , Here is a reference on mysql connection and insert row 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp'

Comment: the mysql connection i think is good. The error comes with the for($i=o;$i<sizeof($ar_name);$i++)

because $i it's not declared in your code , right ?

Comment: The above errors notice which you seen is related to DB connection and query , Ok anyways declare $i and check if it works , if worked then accept my answer by clicking on tick mark on my answer :)

Comment: Okay, but i really don't understand what does the $i variable, so i really don't know how to declare it :(

Comment: $i is for just looping the results of name and manufacturer array.